# I need to combine 2 databases, where I keep the tables from one, but the data from the other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 databases, both called dataweb (these are databases of 2 different sites) I need to put the new tables I have made on site 1, into the database of site 2, without copying the data from site 1, or deleting the data from site 2, any ideas?

MySQL client version: 5.0.51a

Comment: Is this something that you need to do only once or it will be required as a routine process?

Comment: Buy, don't build e.g. if this was SQL Server I'd suggest you look at Red Gate SQL Compare.

Comment: It will be required as a routine process, on multiple sites

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with bash script. E.g. using the next scenario

1. mysql -hdb1host.com -uroot -pxxxxxx -e "use db1; show tables" >
   file1.txt
2. mysql -hdb2host.com -uroot -pxxxxxx -e "use db2; show tables" >
   file2.txt
3. then compare these two files, e.g. with diff command
       http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm
4. take diff output and stream it to files (tables_from_diff1.txt,
   tables_from_diff2.txt).
5. Then make dump for these tables

   mysqldump -hdb1host.com -uroot
           -pxxxxxx db1 [tables from tables_from_diff1.txt] > db1_dump.txt

   mysqldump -hdb2host.com -uroot -pxxxxxx db2 [tables from
           tables_from_diff2.txt]  > db2_dump.txt
6. Apply datadumps to necessary dbs.

   mysql -hdb1host.com -uroot -pxxxxxx db1 < db2_dump.txt

   mysql -hdb1host.com -uroot -pxxxxxx db2 < db1_dump.txt